# Como mudar a cor dos parênteses no vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, background-color

Eu gostaria de mudar a cor dos parênteses no vs code para ter uma visualização melhor do código, mas não consegui. Só fica na cor branca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue habilitar essa funcionalidade pelo settings.json do VS Code.
Para acessar o arquivo você pode usar o comando <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> e digitar `settings.json`.

[image: Print das opções do arquivo settings.json no VS Code]

Pode reparar que aparecerá 3 opções do arquivo, o específico para o usuário, para o workspace e o geral do VS Code. Edite na sua preferência, sabendo que a ordem de preferencia das configurações segue exatamente essa. Ou seja, se no settings.json a configuração estiver setada para `false` e a global em `true`, a configuração `false` prevalecerá.

Seguindo, no arquivo basta adicionar a seguinte chave e valor:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
```

Essa configuração mudará tanto a cor dos parênteses como dos colchetes e chaves também.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Obrigado!